# PHP Accessing jSON - Error - Trying to get property 'amount_formatted' of non-object

Tags: php, json

I am trying to access some data within the json. Here is the json I am accessing

[image]

The code I am using is (I am not posting URL or headers due to it being private):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);


//print_r($response);

$response = json_decode($response);

echo $response->host_transaction_stat->payout_transactions_total->amount_formatted;
```

I receive the following error:
[image]

If I change my echo to

```
echo $response->host_transaction_stat->user_id;
```

It brings back the user_id field, so I know my curl is working correctly obtaining the json.

Comment: payout_transactions_total is an array, so you need to change your code to: `echo $response->host_transaction_stat->payout_transactions_total[0]->amount_formatted;`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect